# Place a div inside another

Tags: html, css

The div map will have it content moving around.

I want the inside div (cyan) be on the bottom right to show a legend. I try with float style and could make it float `left` and `right` but cant find something like `bottom-right`

I'm not really sure if I need float, I only need cyan div on top of map.

Also what if I want it on the right, but in the middle. I try using `Top: 700px` but didnt work.

```css
.map {
    background: url(http://www.theodora.com/maps/new9/time_zones_4.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

.legend {
    top: 700px;
    float: right;
    background-color:cyan;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:double
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
    <div class="legend">Some content! Some content! Some content!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is with `absolute` position: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm87cwze/)

With `absolute` positioning, you can tell it to align with the bottom-right of its direct non- `static` parent (in this case the parent will be `relative`.

```
.map {
    background: url(http://www.theodora.com/maps/new9/time_zones_4.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.legend {
    background-color:cyan;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 2px;
    border-style:double;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

More info on the `position` property: [CSS Position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: This `absolute` positioning within a `relative` positioned element used to confuse me a lot but once you figure out how it works it’s really useful.

Comment: Yes, i tought the same, I remove the relative line to see what happen and things went crazy.